# How can I make scrollable gamefield in Lazarus?

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

I would like make a small RTS game in Lazarus and therefore I would like make a scrollable gamefield with arrow keys in it.
Now I created a bigger TBitmap (a big blue image) on the smaller TForm1 and I draw the game elements on this TBitmap. Although I can move this TBitmap and the elements on it with the arrow keys, but I can't delete the moving units from the previous place.
Maybe the canvas of a TBitmap is can't be deleted? But in this case how can I make a scrollable gamefield?
[image: Game field with moving unit]

Comment: Have you tried invalidating the area of the bitmap canvas which a game element previously occupied just before you deleted it, and then allowing the canvas to repaint itself?

Comment: Hello MartynA! I made a Timer object too, in which when refresh the gamefield, I use the Invalidate command too. So, I move the object on gamefield, then: with gamefield do invalidate;